# Chrome блокирует загрузку моего приложения. В чем проблема?

Tags: c#, консоль

Мое приложение абсолютно безвредное, но хром так не считает. Хочу разобраться, почему он так не считает, чтобы исправить это и чтобы такая ошибка больше не выскакивала (иначе приложение нельзя скачать, пока не отключить защиту в настройках). Что, я думаю, может играть роль:

- Приложение консольное (и весит всего 12кб)
- Приложение отправляет данные на сервер
- Приложение находится на бесплатном файловом хостинге mega.co.nz
- .exe имеет пустые поля: Description, Company, Trademark

Cкорее всего, все это не имеет отношения к проблеме. Но в чем тогда дело - я не пойму. :(

Собственно, ошибка:

[image]

### UPD.

Благодаря подсказкам в комментариях нашел кое-что: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249. Я завтра, пожалуй, все-таки потанцую с бубном. Но уже чувствую, что это не совсем то. Потому что это относится именно к сайту, а не к приложению/программе. Думаю, что mega.co.nz уже давно прошел всякие подобные проверки, ведь сайт то довольно популярный (и существует не первый месяц, хоть и относительно новый).

Comment: Вот даром имя затерли. Возможно там имя "мой_супервирус.exe"

Comment: Возможно, что проблема в названии вашего файла - у меня как-то хром ругалсяz даже на program.exe и заткнулся после переименования

Comment: @KoVadim @DreamChild Эмм, странная штука... Оттёр обратно, теперь видно название файла) Попробую сейчас переименовать файл, хотя не думаю, что это поможет)

Comment: @KoVadim @DreamChild Изменил на "CalcFast.exe". Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @JerryGreen: Может, хром не любит mega.co.nz, типа охраняет пользователя от того, чтоб он чего-нибудь не спиратил? Попробуйте выложить на свой сервер и загрузить оттуда.

Comment: @VladD мой хостер не позволяет скачивать `.exe` с его серверов, поэтому попробовал на локальный сервер загрузить - даже так ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: Так потому что вы неизвестный издатель, гугл вас не знает, и вам не доверяет вот и срабатывает его "защита". В настройках гугла можно поставить галку и проверки не будет либо поставить другую галку и он отправить файл в гугл, если повезет, то через какое-то время ваш файл не будет блокироваться. Для более подробной информации напишите в саппорт гугл хрома.

Comment: А что в выпадающем списке справа от кнопки закрыть? Так, кажется, можно выбрать вариант "Все равно скачать".

Answer (score 1):

Запакуйте в zip и проблема уйдет :)

Comment: @dimka3210 так то да, это самый простой способ. Но это скорее обход проблемы, а не её решение. Мне бы хотелось, все-таки, полностью разобраться в этом вопросе. Принципиально :)

Comment: @dimka3210 лол! Приколи, не помогло :D